# How to pause application while a permission is required

Tags: java, android, android-activity, permissions

I have an Android app that I have to fix (it was not developed by me in the beginning), in the Splash Screen activity, in onCreate method some functions are called that need the read/write permissions for Storage and those for phone status. Before starting these functions, I put the code that requires the permissions in object (Activitycompat.requestPermissions).
In android 9 (api 28) everything works correctly, i.e. the permissions dialog appears and app pauses waiting for the user to choose "allow" or "not allow".
From android 8.1 down (api <= 27), instead the behavior is different, that is, even if the permission dialog appears, the execution of the app continues without waiting for the user's decision, obviously the functions mentioned above are executed and not finding the permissions enabled, the app crashes.
How can I pause the application while the permissions dialog is waiting for user input?
Thanks.

Comment: "In android 9 (api 28) everything works correctly, i.e. the permissions dialog appears and app pauses waiting for the user to choose "allow" or "not allow"" -- that is not how it works in any version of Android. "How can I pause the application while the permissions dialog is waiting for user input?" -- you don't. You reorganize your code to proceed if either you already have permission or proceed from `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, if the user elected to grant you permission.

Comment: FWIW, here is [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) on requesting runtime permissions.